# How to contact border authorities in EU/Schengen countries?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, schengen, eu, officials

For questions about entering a country, people are usually referred to the embassy of said country. Unfortunately, except regarding visa issuance, these often prove rather uninformative.

So how would one contact the actual border authorities of the various EU/Schengen states, for assistance **not** related to visa issuance, but e.g. visa usage, other document requirements, border control procedures and other practical/operational matters?

Comment: Kindly define samples of what type of 'assistance **not** related to visa requirements' that you would want to ask.

Comment: @MarkJohnson assistance related to *entry* requirements.  Border officials are frequently if not usually part of a different division of the government (ministry of the interior or similar, though sometimes the defense ministry) from visa officials (who are usually with the foreign ministry).  Unfortunately, this means that visa officers sometimes give incorrect advice about entry requirements, or about the likelihood that some fact will be of concern to a border officer.

Comment: @phoog I am aware of that, but border officials are mostly required to **enforce** (and not interpret) policy. Thus  the question to the OP about what they want to ask them.

Comment: @MarkJohnson but they are indeed required to make judgments, and they will be more familiar with the practical application of policies guiding those judgments to actual cases than will be the workers in an embassy or consulate.

Comment: @phoog Kindly supply proof for your claim. Most Border Guards Organisations are structured as a police force. They inforce laws, they do not implement them. They check the visa for validity (correct dates not counterfeit oer cancel them when instructed). But if you can prove otherwise that that is what the border police for does, then kindly supply proof for your claim.

Comment: @MarkJohnson my claim is that on entry, the border officer must judge whether the traveler meets the conditions of entry.  If the border officer isn't doing that, who is?

Comment: @phoog Yes, they enforce the Border Code. The Consulat determines this in a deeper manor (ties to the home country etc.) for 3rd Country Citizens when issuing the visa. This is what they are trained (with the policy guidlines) to do. A general claim that they are 'less familiar' than the border guards is simply not true.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The competent bodies in each EU/Schengen state can be reached at the following e-mail addresses (mostly belonging to national departments, i.e. not a specific airport/crossing):

- Austria: bmi-v-6@bmi.gv.at (general), spk-n-schwechat-grenzpolizei@polizei.gv.at (Vienna airport)
- Belgium: dao.immi@police.belgium.eu (operations), border@ibz.fgov.be (policy unit), brunat.immi@police.belgium.eu (Brussels airport)
- Bulgaria: nsgp@mvr.bg
- Croatia: uzg@mup.hr
- Cyprus: *Unknown*
- Czechia: krcpp@mvcr.cz
- Denmark: nuc@politi.dk (general), cph.border@politi.dk (Copenhagen airport)
- Estonia: info@politsei.ee (general), tallinn.lennujaam@politsei.ee (Tallinn airport)
- Finland: rajavartiolaitos@raja.fi (general), hkv@raja.fi (Helsinki airport)
- France: dnpaf-em-cnic@interieur.gouv.fr
- Germany: bpolp.referat.22@polizei.bund.de
- Greece: tes.borderprotection@astynomia.gr
- Hungary: hatarrendfoo@orfk.police.hu (general), rri@rri.police.hu (Budapest airport)
- Iceland: lss.kefairport@logreglan.is
- Ireland: bmu@justice.ie (Dublin airport), gnib_dv@garda.ie (other)
- Italy: gruppo.frontiere@interno.it
- Latvia: rikp@rs.gov.lv (general), lidosta.rkp@rs.gov.lv (Riga airport)
- Lithuania: dvks@vsat.vrm.lt
- Luxembourg: sca@police.etat.lu
- Malta: airport.police@gov.mt
- Netherlands: kcc.kmar@mindef.nl (general), hoofd.doorlaatpost.gb@mindef.nl (Schiphol airport)
- Norway: politidirektoratet@politiet.no (general), bcp.osl@politiet.no (Oslo airport)
- Poland: zg.kg@strazgraniczna.pl **and** zdsc.kg@strazgraniczna.pl
- Portugal: sef@sef.pt
- Romania: pfr@igpf.ro
- Slovakia: suhcp@minv.sk
- Slovenia: smp@policija.si
- Spain: https://sede.mir.gob.es/opencms/export/sites/default/es/contacto/
- Sweden: granspolissektionen.noa@polisen.se
- Switzerland: sektion-grenze@sem.admin.ch

Comment: These email- addresses list the organizations that **enforce** the Schengen Border Code (such has: 3rd county citizens that require a visa: do they have one **yes/no**?). Questions under which conditions a Visa will be issued made to these organizations, which a Consulate issues, will most probably be referred by them to the responsible consulate.

Comment: @MarkJohnson They would never refer you to an embassy (except regarding visa issuance), but the Ministry of Foreign Affairs

Comment: @Crazydre an embassy (or a consulate) is usually an office of the ministry of foreign affairs, isn't it?

Comment: @MarkJohnson this question is explicitly not about "under which conditions a visa will be issued."

Comment: @Crazydre could you add the name of the office or other body belonging to each e-mail address? For example, *mup.hr* is *Ministarstvo unutarnjih poslova,* meaning "Ministry of the Interior," but what is *uzg?* Similarly, even though the meaning of *interieur.gouv.fr* is probably intuitive for almost every English speaker, *dcpaf-em-cnic* is far from obvious, and one might wonder why one should "CC: dcpaf-em-chefs-cnic" or how critical it is to do so. Also, it would help to link to the source page or add a note disclosing the source if there's no page, e.g. "called phone number at [URL]" or so.

Comment: @phoog I'll think of how I can do it without making each point too long, but to answer your questions, UZG=Uprava za granicu, DCPAF-EM=Direction Centrale de la Police aux Frontières État-Major. The "chefs" address is there because the staff on the main address is often surprisingly incompetent, and once they forwarded my question to the "chefs" address, whereby I got a direct reply from that one (it was about whether France stamps residence permit holders)

Comment: Spain: Unknown. That sounds accurate.

Comment: @Obie2.0 I know one, cgef.ucfstc@policia.es, which is to the *Unidad Central de Fronteras*, but they seem to refuse to correspond with the general public. I only list addresses through which ordinary mortals will actually receive assistance

Comment: Many of the border authorities also have phone numbers that you can call, in my experience in some cases this is faster and more helpful than contact by email.

Comment: For most of them, if you drop the "account@" and go to the website at that domain, you can find the name of the place.  many of them will have a language menu allowing you to get an English version of the site.

Comment: @WGroleau Many of them don't post email addresses to the specialised department, or sometimes at all, or sometimes it's not obvious which department is the right one. A lot of the email addresses I got by e-mailing a general inbox and receiving a reply from the relevant department, or by Googling leaked EU documents not actually meant for the public to read.

Answer (score 12):

I am writing my experience with this question which may help few travelers. I have personally contacted at least 3 different border control authorities over email (in Europe) for questions regarding immigration.

In all cases, I contacted the Airport Helpdesk and asked them to redirect question to proper authorities. In all the time I got response from the border control authorities and I received the correct information.

So I would suggest, in case you could not find email/contact of appropriate authorities, just email to Airport helpdesk (where you are interested in contacting border control).

Comment: At worst they'll email you back with the correct email address, rather than forwarding the email on your behalf

Comment: @CSM Not true; often they'll be of zero help at all. Varies a lot