# Do I have more chance to be refused at Schengen border next time?

Tags: schengen, eu, visa-free-entry, denial-of-entry

As a citizen of a country with no visa requirement for entering the Schengen zone, I was given a
"refusal of entry at the border" copy of the document for no justifying the purpose and conditions of stay (E) and somewhat arguable means to return my origin country (G), which was understandable at the moment, as I had an overdue bank statement, saying I have enough funds. But previously had no exceptions like this.

Will this misconception affect my further travelings? Or will be recorded in any information system so border authorities had more chance to interrogate with me more on this?

Comment: It is difficult to answer such questions. In fact, I think we cannot answer such question. You say that (G) was temporary, but what about (E)? They also consider how often you entered (and for how long you stay). But also you should not lie (they are trained to detect them). One common error is to make a small insignificant lie (which officers will interpret you will hide something important).

Comment: @chzzh If your future travel involves destinations / purposes for which you need a visa, you will have to declare the entry refusal in any application that asks about past travel history.

Comment: Although i had a visa .. i was denied to enter poland .. (( No TRAVEL PLAN + HOTEL RESERVATION))

Comment: @MohammedAlkhair do you have a question about that?  If so: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: @MohammedAlkhair oh! I see you have: https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/159199/19400.  You might want to follow the advice in CSM's answer here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no electronic record of the refusal shared between Schengen countries but such a system, the [Entry/Exit System](https://ec.europa.eu/home-affairs/what-we-do/policies/borders-and-visas/smart-borders/ees_en) is currently being implemented. There is probably already some national record of it.

There should be a stamp in your passport that could alert border guards. Legally, it is not in and of itself a reason to refuse entry again but it could obviously invite further scrutiny.

Answer (score 0):

Under the terms of the EU's General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR) you have a right to know what information is held about you by any company or organisation that is in the EU. This applies even if you aren't a EU citizen or resident. However, state organisations do have the right to withhold some information for state-security reasons.

You can ask the immigration authority of the country who refused you entry, and ask for a copy of your records. There may be a charge for this; I think it is capped at €15. We [have a list of how to contact EU immigration authorities](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/153471/how-to-contact-border-authorities-in-eu-schengen-countries/157188#157188), that you can use to determine the contact details.

This is a called a 'subject access request', and you should provide as much information as you can. I would recommend providing

1. Name and date-of-birth
2. Passport number and issuing authority
3. Date and location of attempted entry

They have to respond speedily to the request (I can't remember the timescales), thought they can reply saying the need some time to gather the information