# Effects of being denied entry to Poland

Tags: schengen, poland, denial-of-entry

[image]

I was denied entry to Poland last February. The border guards told me this was because I didn't provide enough supporting documents like hotel reservations and travel plans. Will this affect my chances of entering other European countries in the future?

Comment: That looks like it happened on the first day of February 2020.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this will affect your chance to enter any other European countries, and probably some non-European countries as well.  But it won't normally result in an automatic refusal.

A past refusal of entry will certainly serve as a red flag to any visa officer or border officer who is evaluating whether to grant you a visa or allow you into a country.  But if the reason for a refusal is simply a lack of sufficient supporting documents, it shouldn't prejudice a future decision maker against you.

Comment: Provided, of course, that next time you do have a full set of supporting documents. I suggest having very definite and precise plans, with everything scheduled and reserved.

Comment: Thanks for answers.. do you suggest me to get a new passport!! Does it help increase my chances!

Comment: @MohammedAlkhair I don't think getting a new passport will help very much. The best advice is Patricia Shanahan's: make sure you understand the criteria that border officers will apply and that you met them. Have evidence of your itinerary and accommodation and your reserve funds, and be prepared to explain exactly what you lacked when you were refused. Looking at it with some pessimism, there is also the unfortunate possibility of discrimination. Dress well. Consider filling a subject access request for your file to see if there is any evidence that they have mistaken you for someone else.

Comment: Correct if I'm wrong but I was under the assumption that there still isn't a common database for entry refusals in the Schengen area? So if OP changes their passport countries other than Poland won't know about it. There is a database for visa refusals but not for mere entry refusals, AFAIK. Obviously you should never lie if directly asked about passed entry refusals but it doesn't hurt to change your passport to avoid awkward questions.

Comment: @JonathanReez assuming that no alert was entered into the Schengen Information System, which seems unlikely given the facts presented here, that is correct.