# I overstayed in Schengen. Will that cause trouble for future trips or visas in the EU or UK?

Tags: visas, schengen, overstaying

I was a full-term student studying in Poland. After my internship training I was waiting for my certificate and license from the government which took a bit longer time than expected. So I stayed with my Schengen visa after my student visa expired. However, I was extremely sick when the Schengen visa reached 90 days; I had to stay 7 days more.

After I recovered, with all legalized documents proving my license and internship I left via Germany back to my country. The border police asked me many questions about my overstay in Poland. But after I showed them my documents they eventually let me go without a special stamp in  my passport.

Now I’m kinda worried. Will there be any issue with my future working visa application to the EU or UK?
Is there any record I should be aware of?
Or maybe in the future will they decide to give me some punishment?
Could something still be happening?

Comment: If you were in any sort of trouble you would know. Upon exiting the Schengen area the border police would've made you aware and you would have had to sign documents. You are probably fine, but no one can know unless you travel and try again. Anything we say on your topic specifically is an educated guess at best.

Comment: It sounds like "I was waiting for my certificate and license and then I got sick" was an explanation for the overstay that the border officials were ok with. (There were probably dates on the documents to help show you were telling the truth.)

Comment: Do/did you have a doctor's note, hospital discharge papers, health insurance documents, or anything to prove you were ill?

Comment: I didn’t have medical proof documents. During Christmas break the nearest ER was 70 Km away from my place and I was too weak to leave my bed. My documents for my license did have date from the end of December 2023 and January 2024. Also I gave them all documents I had to proof my staying in Poland was totally legit.

Answer (score 4):

Under the EU's General Data Protection Regulation (GDPR), you can request a copy of all the information the immigration authorities hold about you. This is called a Subject Access Request (SAR). The reply will indicate if you have a restriction on reentry.

You probably want to send one to both the German and Polish authorities. There's a list of the contacts here https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153472/47175